# Failed Binder Transaction error on listview image click

Tags: android, listview, screen

I have a listview getting only news images from json. When image clicked a new activity runs and shows the news details. This works fine in small screens. Now I created layout-large and layout-xlarge folder and put list.xml into folders. I editted image dimensions for large screen. When i run application on small screen device, image click (listview item) works fine but gives FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION on 10 inches virtual device. how can I fix it?

Comment: dont pass a Bitmap as an extra